ARG variable in Dockerfile not expanding
I'm very new to Docker (this is the first time I try it after reading a few tutorials) and I'm stuck on something that seems very simple.
I have this lines in my Dockerfile that are supposed to build a dotnet app, and as you can see I have an ARG where I define the build configuration and then I pass it to the compiler in the next line:
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION} -o /bin

However the problem is that, when building the Docker image, the ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION} arg does not get expanded, but is instead passed in literally so the build command that is actaully invoked is literally:
dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION} -o /bin

Obviously the compiler doesn't like that and gives me the error:

MSB3052: The parameter to the compiler is invalid,
'/define:${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}' will be ignored.

Why is this not working? What am I missing?
NOTE: I've also tried $BUILD_CONFIGURATION without the curly braces, and also tried using ENV instead of ARG, but the result is the same.
EDIT: some further info if needed

I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows 11
I'm invoking the build process from the Windows Terminal with the command docker build .
This is the full dockerfile if it's any help:

Dockerfile
#Copy source code into container
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .    
#Build application
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION} -o /bin


Did you change your SHELL value in the Dockerfile (or in the base image)? And if so, how does that shell expand environment variables?

@BMitch: I didn't do anything with the shell, and I'm quite new to docker, I'm just trying to get one project to compile for now. I'm using the latest version of Docker Desktop on Windows 11 if that is any help. And I'm not passing the ARG via the shell, so I would assume it would expand to the default value of "Release" as I've set it in the first line you can see above. I've edited the question with the full dockerfile in case it is any help.

Please see [mcve] for details about providing an example that we can reproduce. Your "full Dockerfile" is not a full dockerfile, it's not usable by others trying to recreate your issue.

I attempted your example using linux alpine base image, but for me in the console it prints the variable while running docker build .
Here is Dockerfile:
FROM alpine
#Copy source code into container
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .    
#Build application
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION} -o /bin

Here is output:
....
 => [2/4] WORKDIR /src                                                                                     0.1s
 => [3/4] COPY . .                                                                                         0.3s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /bin                           0.3s
------                                                                                                          
 > [4/4] RUN dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /bin:
0.323 /bin/sh: dotnet: not found
...

Although it is outputting error but at least it is printing Release as part of log, which proves that it is working for linux base image...
Edit
Since you are using windows based base image, the environment variables are evaluated using %% rather than $ symbol. So you can modify your run command to make it working:
dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /bin


It is indeed a Windows image (I need that because my application uses some Win APIs). As I said, I'm very new to docker.... if I'm understanding correctly you're saying the commands in the Dockerfile behave differently depending on the image you're using? Seems to kinda defeat the purpose of Docker, but probably it's just my ignorance....

@Master_T In windows we have "command prompt" while Linux/Mac have "Terminal" and they both behave differently. In Windows the environment variables are evaluated using %% rather than $ symbol. I would say give it a try using: dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /bin and see if it works

Also if this does not work, then can you share the base image name? I can try to recreate your issue

that was it! Using % instead of $ worked. If you want to write that in an answer or edit your answer to reflect that I'll accept it.

@Master_T great!! I have edited the answer to include this information
